# ng-repeat not working when element repeat in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html

```
<div ng-app="person" ng-controller="names">
<div ng-repeat="id in ids">
{{id}}
</div>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
var persons=angular.module("person",[]);
persons.controller("names",function($scope){
$scope.ids=['vicky','a','c','svicky'];
});
```

This is working fine as expected [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7df1g0g/)

But when i change the last element from 'svicky' to 'vicky' it is not working

[fiddle which is not working](https://jsfiddle.net/j7df1g0g/1/)

Why is this happening?

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="id in ids track by $index">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use track by $index as the console tells you. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0j6kr6t/)

```
<div ng-app="person" ng-controller="names">
<div ng-repeat="id in ids track by $index">
{{id}}
</div>
</div>
```

This is the error you should see in the console with your non-working example:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use
>   'track by'